# update de linhas seguidas de acordo com itens selecionados no listview

Tags: c#, sql

temos uma tabela 1, que tem prédio e salas, prédio A, sala01, sala 02...., precisamos colocar pessoas nessas salas. Essas pessoas vem de outra tabela(2), que preenche o listview. Esse lvi tem checkboxes e é multiselect. Vai fazer como? Seleciona as pessoas pelos checkboxes e clica num botão para colocar cada pessoa numa sala, em sequencia. Se selecionar a pessoa 1, a pessoa 4, a pessoa 7, deve colocar a pessoa 1 na sala 1, a pessoa 4 na sala 2, a pessoa 7 na sala 3, direto no banco pra exibição no grid....estou fazendo isso assim:

```
 private void btnAlocar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView2.CheckedItems)
            {
                if (item.Checked == true)
                {
                    int j = listView2.CheckedItems.Count;
                    try
                    {
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexaoString);

                        con.Open();

                        for (int i = 0; i < (j); i++)
                        {
                            var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE salas SET
                            nomePessoa=@nomePessoa, cargo=@cargo, idPessoa=@idPessoa WHERE idSala=@idSala", con);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idSala", Convert.ToInt32(dgvSalas.CurrentRow.Cells["idSala"].Value.ToString()));

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomePessoa", item.SubItems[0].Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idPessoa", Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[3].Text));

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show($"Erro ao alocar Pessoa: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexaoString);
                        this.salasTableAdapter.Fill(this.bdDataSet.salas);

                        con.Close();
                        con.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

ele faz a inserção, mas de uma pessoa só, não estou conseguindo que passe pra linha seguinte e insira os demais selecionados, onde estou errando, não consigo achar o erro....

Answer (score 0):

Na linha

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idSala", Convert.ToInt32(dgvSalas.CurrentRow.Cells["idSala"].Value.ToString()));
```

Onde você atualiza `dgvSalas.CurrentRow`? Porque me parece que você está sobrescrevendo o usuário naquela sala com cada `UPDATE`...

Comment: eu estou usando essa como linha de partida. deveria começar a inserir nessa linha, na coluna pessoa. Fiz update pq a tabela é preenchida em várias etapas, e nesse ponto já tem dados, então tem que ser update...

Comment: o que eu não consigo é fazer ele andar as linhas, tentei assim:

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idSala", Convert.ToInt32(dgvSalas.CurrentRow.Cells["idSala"].Value.ToString())+i);

Comment: pq queria que ele fosse pro proximo idsala, com o +i, daí colocou outro nome mas onde ele quis...

Comment: tentei escrever assim, se foram selecionados 3 nomes, faça o update na coluna nome, na linha idsala onde está o cursor, inserindo cada nome checado, linha a linha....

Comment: Consegui. Não precisava do for, só o foreach já resolvia....